# MySQL get rank from particular row ID

Tags: mysql

I have list of hospitals under that there are average ratings already calculated. Now I wanted to calculate rank for list of hospitals according to their average ratings from following query

```
SELECT    name,
          hospitalID,
          currentAvgRating,
          @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM      hospitals h, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
ORDER BY  currentAvgRating DESC
```

Now above query works when I want to see all hospitals from table but when I apply WHERE clause like below then result is wrong since with this it takes row position.

```
SELECT    name,
          hospitalID,
          currentAvgRating,
          @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM      hospitals h, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r where hospitalID = '453085'
ORDER BY  currentAvgRating DESC
```

Is there any way to get correct result when we apply where clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you proceed what you just found out, logically ("when there is only 1 listitem, it cannot be ordered") - you will come to the conclusion that you NEED to select ALL rows. But nothing wrong with that, you can pack them into a subselect (which isnt even an expensive one) and apply the WHERE to that:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT    name,
            hospitalID,
            currentAvgRating,
            @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
  FROM      hospitals h, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
  ORDER BY  currentAvgRating DESC
) toplist
WHERE toplist.hospitalID = 453085
```

Comment: Thanks for this.. Is it possible if many hospitals have same average rating then it should give same rank to all which are same avg rating. Currently it counts as row position. If such thing is possible then please help..

Answer (score 1):

Wrap in a subquery.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT    name,
              hospitalID,
              currentAvgRating,
              @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
    FROM      hospitals h, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
    ORDER BY  currentAvgRating DESC
)
WHERE hospitalID = '453085'
```

Comment: Thanks for this.. Is it possible if many hospitals have same average rating then it should give same rank to all which are same avg rating. Currently it counts as row position. If such thing is possible then please help..

Comment: Sorry MySQL isn't my specialty. In SQL Server you would use `DENSE_RANK` function. If you can work out the equivalent then you could use that.